# Select one row from multiple rows based on one field

Tags: mysql

I have 1 relevant table for this question, award :

```
----------------------------------------
| award                                |
----------------------------------------
| id | name | URL | country_id | point |
----------------------------------------
  1  | A    | a   | 1          | 120
  2  | A    | b   | 0          | 60
  3  | A    | b   | 2          | 80
  4  | B    | c   | 0          | 50
  5  | B    | d   | 1          | 70
```

I want to be able to get for a list of given countries, the corresponding different awards (a same award has the same name) with the highest value for the column `point`.

So I tried ordering my request by point DESC, and grouping by name, but it didn't do the trick, I didn't get the right number of points  nor the right URL.

I know I could do that easily by getting all the data from the table then keeping only the row with the best number of points, but there must be a way to do that with SQL only !

The request I tried was :

```
SELECT name, URL, point FROM award WHERE country_id IN (0,1) ORDER BY point DESC GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you what you are looking for:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM award AS t1
   INNER JOIN (SELECT name, MAX(point) AS point
      FROM award
      WHERE country_id IN (0,1)
      GROUP BY name) AS t2
   ON t1.name=t2.name
      AND t1.point=t2.point;
```

Here is how it breaks down:

This is joining the `award` table (identified as `t1`) with a subquery that is identified as `t2`. The subquery looks like this:

```
SELECT name, MAX(point) AS point
    FROM award
    WHERE country_id IN (0,1)
    GROUP BY name
```

The subquery will return the maximum amount of points for each name. Here are the results of the subquery:

```
+------+-------+
| name | point |
+------+-------+
| A    |   120 |
| B    |    70 |
+------+-------+
```

Obviously this doesn't include the `URL`. If it did then `URL` would have to be in the `GROUP BY` and then you're entries would be the unique combination of `name` and `URL` (and then you wouldn't get the max point value).

The next step is to essentially join to this temporary table to get the rows in the `award` table that match.

```
INNER JOIN (...) AS t2
    ON t1.name=t2.name
       AND t1.point=t2.point;
```

The join finds the rows in the `award` table where `name` and `point` match `name` and `point` in the results of the subquery. This gives us the full rows that we want - and we can now access the `URL`. The result looks like this:

```
+------+------+------+------------+-------+
| id   | name | URL  | country_id | point |
+------+------+------+------------+-------+
|    1 | A    | a    |          1 |   120 |
|    5 | B    | d    |          1 |    70 |
+------+------+------+------------+-------+
```

Also, at this point you can order by an column in the `award` table you want, for example name:

```
ORDER BY t1.name
```

or highest point value:

```
ORDER BY t1.point DESC
```

Comment: It worked for me, but there could be a problem if there are different rows with the same name and the same number of points : the URL could be wrong (not from the good row).

Comment: Which row would you want to return in that case (i.e. which is the "good row")? If you include country_id in the group by and join then you will get the max points per name / country. Not sure if that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the point desc, try it

```
    SELECT name, country_id, point
FROM `award`
WHERE country_id IN (0,1)
GROUP BY name, country_id
ORDER BY name, point DESC
```

result

```
    name |country_id  |point
    =====|============|===========  
    A    |1           |120
    A    |0           |60
    B    |1           |70
    B    |0           |50
```

Comment: I guess my question wasn't clear enough. The aim here is to get only one row per name, the one with the highest value in point.